# running eagle on Fedora 37

Tags: mesa

Im trying to run Eagle on Fedora 37, but it doesnt work. it worked prior to updating from fedora 35.
Im running in like this QT_XCB_GL_INTEGRATION=xcb_egl ./eagle and get the followng output:

`pci id for fd 6: 1002:73bf, driver (null) libEGL warning: DRI3: No driver found libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/lib64/dri) pci id for fd 7: 1002:73bf, driver (null) libEGL warning: DRI3: No driver found libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/lib64/dri) Could not initialize GLX Aborted (core dumped)` 
what could it be?

thanks,
Jonas

tried reinstalling all the mesa and libgl stuff but nothing helped.
packages are up to date. GPU is a rx6800XT

Comment: my solution to get eagle working on archlinux was to delete `/opt/eagle/qt.conf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, my solution was to delete the libEGL.so.1 library packaged with Eagle in the lib directory. It seems that this version of the library is incompatible with the drivers provided with Fedora 37. Now Eagle is forced to use the libEGL library provided with the OS as well and I am able to run it all right.

Comment: Same for Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

Here are notes from my getting Eagle PCB to run on my Fedora 37 laptop. I hope they help you out.

#################################################
Eagle PCB Installation Notes
JCL
10 March 2023

After much messing about, I managed to get Eagle running smoothly on three linux/Fedora37 systems today, including desktop launchers for each app. There have been numerous issues that I've addressed to get things working easily on Fedora. Below are some notes.

```
framewk 140= uname -a
Linux framewk 6.1.12-200.fc37.x86_64 #1 SMP 

PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Feb 15 04:35:34 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

framewk 116= pwd
/home/jcl/bin

Note: Verify bash script is executable. If not, execute the following command: chmod ugo+x startEagle.bash)

framewk 117= ls -l
total 4
drwxr-x---. 1 jcl jcl 198 Mar  9 09:54 eagle-9.6.2/
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 jcl jcl 245 Mar 10 09:48 startEagle.bash*

framewk 123= cat startEagle.bash 
#!/bin/bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64 QT_XCB_GL_INTEGRATION=xcb_egl /home/jcl/bin/eagle-9.6.2/eagle&

Note: Check executable permissions
framewk 119= ll eagle-9.6.2/eagle
-rwxr-x--x. 1 jcl jcl 22150216 May 19  2020 eagle-9.6.2/eagle*

### Now set up the launcher for desktop double-click start
framewk 129= pwd
/home/jcl/.local/share/applications

Note: Create a desktop launcher file called "eagle.desktop"
framewk 130= cat eagle.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Icon=/home/jcl/eagleIcon.png
Name=EaglePCB
Exec=/home/jcl/bin/startEagle.bash
Terminal=false

Note: Check perms 
framewk 131= ls -l eagle.desktop 
-rw-r--r--. 1 jcl jcl 126 Mar 10 10:34 eagle.desktop

Note: I used the LTSpice icon (256X256 png file) since I don't (yet) have one for Eagle. It worked fine. I made a copy and named it "eagleIcon.png".

Note: To get Eagle to run at all, I had to rename file "qt.conf" to take it out of play (mv qt.conf qt.conf.save)
framewk 137= pwd
/home/jcl/bin/eagle-9.6.2
framewk 138= ls -l qt*
-rw-r-----. 1 jcl jcl 145 May 19  2020 qt.conf.save

Note: Desktop using "wayland"
framewk 139= 
framewk 139= echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland

framewk 142= env | grep QT
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
QT_XCB_GL_INTEGRATION=xcb_egl

Note: In case relevant, below are the contents of my /etc/gdm/custom.conf file. I may have changed the waylandEnable flag to false but cannot remember for sure. I was trying all kinds of things suggested in various web articles.

framewk 106= pwd
/etc/gdm
framewk 107= cat custom
custom.conf       custom.conf.save  
framewk 107= cat custom.conf
# GDM configuration storage

[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
DefaultSession=gnome-xorg.desktop

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
#Enable=true
```